# Estrutura de dados, bag of words, dúvidas sobre a estrutura do código

Tags: python, pandas, estrutura-de-dados

Olá! estou estudando análise de sentimento para a conclusão de uma iniciação científica, cujo tema é "A influência das redes sociais no mercado financeiro"

No código estão presentes os modelos de extração de dados do twitter usando `snscrape.modules.twitter`, após extrair os dados, é só upar o arquivo no ambiente de execução do COLAB. Em seguida começa a implementação do modelo de bag of words, onde usamos o `CountVectorizer`para ver a frequência de palavras. Sou bem iniciante em python e por isso queria ajuda para fazer o tratamento dos dados, eliminando conjunções, preposições e artigos definidos e indefinidos, além dos usuários mencionados nos tweets logo após o "@".

Concluindo isso, preciso colocar o texto em função do tempo para construir um gráfico que diga mais ou menos a frequência dessas palavras no tempo.

O código está no COLAB no seguinte link: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1QGb8vsipDq8wq4uxn_jQzH75PHJzgYa4?usp=sharing

Ou aqui:

```
#Extração com snscrape
import snscrape.modules.twitter as sntwitter
import csv

csvFile = open('place_result4.csv', 'a', newline='', encoding='utf8')
csvWriter = csv.writer(csvFile)
csvWriter.writerow(['id','date','tweet',]) 
for i,tweet in enumerate(sntwitter.TwitterSearchScraper('from:@cafecomferri + since:2020-02-01 until:2020-11-05').get_items()):
    csvWriter.writerow([tweet.id, tweet.date, tweet.content])
csvFile.close()

#Com os dados já extraídos e prontos no ambiente de trabalho, começar pela importação das bibliotecas.
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
import nltk
#Todas as bibliotecas estão importadas e o Count Vectorizer também. 

dataset = pd.read_csv("place_result4.csv")
#Nesse ponto, a importação do dataset precisa estar de acordo com o formato do arquivo csv extraído pelo snscrape

print(dataset)
#O dataset importado possui duas colunas das quais em uma aparece o ID e na outra aparece o Tweet

vectorizer = CountVectorizer()
#Atribuímos o countVectorizer à uma variável. Instanciando-a

vectorizer.fit(dataset["tweet"])
#O Vectorizer atribuido ao dataset faz uma limpa no vocabulário e conta a frequência de cada palavra.

print(vectorizer.vocabulary_)
#Nesse ponto, o vectorizer pegou os dados apenas da primeira linha. Provavelmente preciso fazer um Row pra cada linha


#Falta agora  limpar esses dados (o que eu não sei fazer) e construir um gráfico em função do tempo(fornecido pelo snscrape no arquivo csv).
```

Por favor me ajudem, isso é fundamental para que eu apresente minha IC no próximo dia 24 de fevereiro.

Comment: Olá. Você tentou fazer e está dando um erro específico que precisa de ajuda (isso estaria dentro do escopo do site) ou apenas quer saber alguma forma de fazer (acredito que aí não estaria)?

Comment: Opa! sim, queria alguma forma de fazer. Isso não está no escopo do site?

Comment: Não porque seria uma solução personalizada para o seu cenário, e não uma solução pontual de programação que sirva para ajudar outras pessoas em diversos cenários, que é o intuito do site. Mas se você identificar uma forma de fazer e tiver uma dúvida mais de programação, pode vir perguntar pra gente.

Comment: Também aproveite e faça o [tour]

Comment: Ok, obrigado. Sabe onde posso conseguir ajuda para fazer uma resposta personalizada?

Comment: Talvez em alguma outra comunidade online de Python, ciência de dados ou de programação em geral, que permita dúvidas mais genéricas. Algumas podem falar português. Para o seu problema específico é preciso ter noção de orientação a objetos em Python (se já não tiver, porém é um conceito amplo) a fim de entender de maneira geral a documentação das bibliotecas que irá necessitar e a forma de programar, como a dessa CountVectorizer (que deve ter algum recurso de omitir certas palavras do conjunto trabalhado) e da tal que gera gráficos. Também buscar por exemplos de uso delas pode ajudar.